# delete item from a list value in dictionary Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, object, indexing

I am trying to delete an item from a list which is set as value in a dictionary, the dictionary is a self object which looks like this

```
    {'battleship': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4']}
```

I have a variable saved with the giving element to delete from the list:

```
    shot_pose = "A3"
```

Expected output:

```
    {'battleship': ['A1', 'A2', 'A4']}
```

the code gives me **TypeError** , my full code:

```
    class Game:
    
        def __init__(self):
    
            self.__dictionary = {'battleship': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4']}
    
        def printout(self):
    
            print(self.__dictionary)
    
        def update_dictionary(self):
            shot_pose = "A3"
    
            for positions in self.__dictionary.values():
                for place in positions:
                    if place == shot_pose:
                        del positions[place]
            print(self.__dictionary)
    
    def main():
    
        game = Game()
        game.printout()
        game.update_dictionary()
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Later on while creating the rest of the program, this shot position will be an entry that the user enters, that is why I did not just select the key from the dictionary by myself and trying to build it around an entry that will be given and saved in a variable.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have edited the post with the full code now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to replace `del positions[place]` by `positions.remove(place)` in order to remove `"A3"`

or you can directly delete it with the index using:
`self.__dictionary['battleship'].remove(shot_pose)`

the ouput is the same as the one you expected.

Answer (score 1):

Type of the

> positions

is list. So the error occured because of

> del positions[place]

My answer is

```
__dictionary = {'battleship': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4']}
shot_pose = "A3"
for positions in __dictionary.values():
    if shot_pose in positions:
        positions.remove(shot_pose)
print(__dictionary)
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your support! got it fixed :)) !

Answer (score -1):

i dont know if this is what you are looking for but here you go:

```
a = {'battleship': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4']}

shot_pose = "A3"

a['battleship'].remove(shot_pose)

print(a)
```

if it is not please give full code and expected output.

Comment: Why are you giving an answer to something **you yourself** aren't sure they are asking for?

Comment: maybe because his question's not clear at all ?

Comment: I am sorry for the inconvenient situation I caused, I thought to write simply and focused where the issue is might be more helpful, but here is the code fully written up there now

Comment: @Joel sorry for trying to help people without knowing what they really asking for because they didnt ask the question properly